# auth()->user() returns null in ServiceProvider when Feature testing

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I have a code I wrote for Role permissions that loads up through a ServiceProvider.

It works fine generally, but for some reason in Feature Tests auth()->user() returns null;

I am "actingAs()" in the test.

Any idea why this works just fine normally but fails to give me an id in feature tests?

```
public function boot()
    {
        try {
            dd(auth()->user()); // => return null
            Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) {
                Gate::define($permission->slug, function ($user) use ($permission) {
                    return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
                });
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            report($e);
            return false;
        }
}
```

What is the problem?